# Getting interface MTU under Linux with PCAP

Tags: linux, mtu, pcap

I am interested in storing packets I sniff using PCAP.

As I preallocate the memory I need - i.e. a multiple of the MTU of the interface I am sniffing from, I would like to discover how much memory I need before opening the live session.

Is it possible to query PCAP for getting the MTU of the sniffed interface ?

How can I get this information otherwise (possibly using system libraries) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a straightforward way to do so in PCAP (no API).

However, for Linux >=2.6 [Solvent](https://serverfault.com/users/111176/solvent) posted a simple solution that is reading a file like the following: `/sys/class/net/INTERFACE_X/mtu`. It is trivial to do it in C.

```
int getMTU(char *name) {
FILE *f;
char buf[128];
char *line = NULL;
ssize_t count;
size_t len = 0;
int mtu;

snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "/sys/class/net/%s/mtu", name);
f = fopen(buf, "r");
if(!f) {
    perror("Error opening:");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
count = getline(&line, &len, f);

if (count == -1) {
    perror("Error opening:");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
sscanf(line, "%d\n", &mtu);
fclose(f);

return mtu;
}
```

Reading the PCAP source, I found out that the PCAP developers used a more complex, yet elegant solution to read the interface MTU invoking `ioctl`. This is a simplified version I wrote:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>

int get_mtu(int fd, const char *device) {
struct ifreq ifr;

if (!device)
    return 65535;

memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, device, sizeof(ifr.ifr_name));

if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFMTU, &ifr) == -1) {
    perror("Error opening:");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

return ifr.ifr_mtu;
}
```

For further references, `man netdevice` is suggested.

Answer (score 4):

One option on linux would be the sysfs file mtu in /sys/class/net/devicename

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/eth0/mtu /sys/class/net/lo/mtu
1500
16436
```